# Open AI Functions API: specifying more complex (list, lists of lists) parameter types for functions

Tags: openai-api

Am I able to specify that a parameter is to be a list of lists (of e.g. strings) in my function description?

Here is what I have, followed by the error:

```
FUNCS_DESC_create_pptx = { # create_pptx(new_file_name, title, subtitle, slide_titles, slide_bullets, filepath_to_save=None):
    "name": "create_pptx",
    "description": "Creates a (powerpoint) presentation for the user.",
    "parameters": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "new_file_name": {
                "type": "string",
                "description": "The name of the new text file to be created; should be descriptive and concise. It will be saved as {new_file_name}.pptx automatically.",
            },
            "title": {
                "type": "string",
                "description": "The title of the presentation, for the first slide.",
            },
            "subtitle": {
                "type": "string",
                "description": "The subtitle of the presentation, this also goes on the first slide.",
            },
            "slide_titles": {
                "type": "list[string]",
                "description": "The list of slide titles for the presentation, for each slide.",
            },
            "slide_bullets": {
                "type": "list[list[string]]",
                "description": "The list of bullet points for each slide inr the presentation; each item is a list of strings, each of those strings is a bullet point.",
            },
        },
        "required": ["new_file_name", "title", "subtitle", "slide_titles", "slide_bullets"],
    },
    
}
```

Error:

```
 File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\openai\resources\chat\completions.py", line 645, in create
    return self._post(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\openai\_base_client.py", line 1088, in post
    return cast(ResponseT, self.request(cast_to, opts, stream=stream, stream_cls=stream_cls))
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\openai\_base_client.py", line 853, in request
    return self._request(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\openai\_base_client.py", line 930, in _request
    raise self._make_status_error_from_response(err.response) from None
openai.BadRequestError: Error code: 400 - {'error': {'message': "Invalid schema for function 'create_pptx': 
'list[list[string]]' is not valid under any of the given schemas.", 'type': 'invalid_request_error', 'param': None, 'code': None}}
```

Interestingly it mentions the `list[list[string]]` rather than the `list[string]` before it, so maybe the former is pushing it a little too far?

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.